# Re-Indexing MySQL INT Primary Keys & Reset AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, mysql, database, auto-increment

So I have a MySQL database that I'm using with a PHP site.  Over the course of weeks of development, I'm left with something like:

```
Table: users

id  | name
-----------
  12| Bob
  34| Jen
 155| John
 154| Kyle
```

Except this goes on for hundreds of records and the ids are in the thousands.

I'm looking for a script I can run to re-name the keys to their lowest value (preserving their respective rows), and then reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the next id

The desired output would be:

```
Table: users

id  | name
-----------
   1| Bob
   2| Jen
   3| Kyle
   4| John
```

And `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;`

(Notice `Kyle` and `John`)

I realize I would have to fix anything referencing the `users.id`.

Does anyone know a way to do this in MySQL or with  a PHP script?

Comment: I did this earlier by removing droping the ID column and creating it again, I'm not sure how this will affect the ordering however. Edit: I suggest you perform a backup before trying anything like this however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove index on id

do something like this:

```
SET @rank:=0;
update users
set id=@rank:=@rank+1
order by id;
```

add index on id

Comment: This worked but it didn't fix the default order. It still lists as `1,2,4,3` http://i.imgur.com/YB6oE.png (stop deleting your comments and making me looks silly =[)

Comment: @imoda If you do a simple query like `select * from t`, you don't have to expect any order. The order of table rows is undefined. Sometimes you can get different results when running the same query multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to change the order of the names in the database? You can just add an `ORDER BY name` clause on your sql query to get the results in alphabetical order by name.

Comment: I don't want to sort them alphabetically by name.  I want them to sort by `id` by default, that way I don't have to tag on `ORDER BY` parameters site wide for my queries.

Comment: Try `alter table yourtable order by id`, though if you're using InnoDB, this will most likely have no effect.

Comment: I had a moment where I thought that perhaps REPLACE...SELECT would work, but the documentation says that you cannot reference the same table name as both the REPLACE (actually in the insert documentation) target and the SELECT target.  I think your best bet may be to use an PHP script to create temporary copy of your Users table, then use REPLACE...SELECT with an ORDER BY, and finish by dropping your temporary table.  This is all, of course, assuming that the statement recommended by @Marc B didn't work.

Comment: Another thought is to create a function that will return the results of the Users in alphabetical order using ORDER BY, then you only have to write the ORDER BY clause once, plus it may DRY up your code ^.^